# Cannot permanently save enviromental variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to save one variable permanently so I won't have to use `export` every time, but I cannot find my mistake and it doesn't get saved.

The variable is `LFS="/mnt/lfs"`.

I saved in `.bash_profile`, `/root/.bash_profile` and in `/.bashrc`.

Those three files that I opened were blank, I don't know why they are blank or if they should be blank.

Comment: Are you sure your shell is bash? Also, do you mean `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`? Adding `export` to the assignment would wark the variable for export, too.

Comment: shell is bash yes. I do mean  ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc
What do you mean by: Adding export to the assignment would wark the variable for export

Comment: at first I wanted to modify .profile 
however at that file it is written that :
~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.

I did added in .bash_profile the following: export LFS=/mnt/lfs
However the enviromental variable was not saved...

Comment: Have you restarted your session after changing the profile?

Comment: Yes. However I modified .bash_profile and not .profile

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'export LFS="/mnt/lfs"' >> ~/.bashrc
```